# SQL is not throwing an error with my procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make this procedure to verify an employee and display an error message if the id number of the employee exists in the database. I check it with valid numbers it displays the employee but when I do employees that do not exist, I do not get an error message like I'm supposed to.

I've tried if/else and try/catch. I do not know where I'm messing up.

```
DROP PROCEDURE spVerifedEmployeeByID  
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spVerifedEmployeeByID   
    @EmployeeID  INT = NULL
AS 
    IF @EmployeeID IS NOT NULL
        SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
        FROM Person.Person p
        JOIN HumanResources.Employee e ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
        WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @EmployeeID 
    ELSE 
        @EmployeeID != e.BusinessEntityID 

    BEGIN
        PRINT( 'Not a valid Employee ID')
    END

/*BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) AS FullName
    FROM Person.Person p
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
    ON p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @EmployeeID 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'Not a valid Employee ID' 
END CATCH
END*/
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you are just checking wether the argument sent to the stored procedure is not null, not if an employee with such id exists in your table.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what I'm messing up now that you pointed it out. Thanks!

Comment: Do NOT use print to provide information to an application. And don't encourage lazy developers. Throw an error if no value (or incorrect value) was provided as the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RandomUser said in comments, you are only checking if an employee is passed, not whether an employee exists in the database.

For example, imagine you passed an `@EmployeeID` that did not exist. The IF statement checks if the `@EmployeeID IS NOT NULL` - which it isn't, therefore it goes to the SELECT statement. Unfortunately, the SELECT statement will return nothing.

I suggest a change in the IF component to check if the `@EmployeeID` exists in the database e.g.,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM Person.Person p
           JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
               ON p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
           WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @EmployeeID
           )
    BEGIN

        SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) AS FullName
        FROM Person.Person p
        JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
            ON p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
        WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @EmployeeID 

    END
ELSE   -- @EmployeeID  != e.BusinessEntityID 
    BEGIN 
 
        PRINT( 'Not a valid Employee ID')

    END;
```

Alternatively, you can do the read only once (assuming all employees have valid first, middle, and lastnames)

```
DECLARE @FullName nvarchar(300);

SELECT @FullName = CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName)
    FROM Person.Person p
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
        ON p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @EmployeeID;

IF @FullName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FullName AS FullName;

    END
ELSE   -- @EmployeeID  != e.BusinessEntityID 
    BEGIN 
 
        PRINT( 'Not a valid Employee ID')

    END;
```

Note - you may want to change the error 'PRINT' to a 'SELECT' as the user is expecting a SELECT result - but it's up to you.